# eBay API returns 'Application ID invalid' in sandbox, but works in production

Tags: python, url, ebay-api

Say, I have the following urls:

> http://open.api.sandbox.ebay.com/shopping?MaxEntries=2&QueryKeywords=pen&AvailableItemsOnly=false&version=681&siteid=0&appid=appid&callname=FindProducts&responseencoding=XML

and

> http://open.api.ebay.com/shopping?callname=FindProducts&responseencoding=XML&appid=appid&siteid=0&version=681&QueryKeywords=pen&AvailableItemsOnly=true&MaxEntries=2

The first one produces the following error:

> 2012-09-19T11:32:33.794Z Failure
>    Application ID invalid.
>   Application ID invalid.
>   1.20 Error
>   RequestError 
>   E791_CORE_BUNDLED_15340089_R1 791

while the second one does not. I've checked multiple times and appid are the same in both urls, so the problem not with appid.

The first url formed from my python code:

```
import requests
d=dict(appid = app_id, siteid = site_id, version = version)

d.update(user_params)
data = requests.get(endpoint, params=d)
```

What could be the source of the problem? Why do two seemingly similar urls behave differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`http://open.api.sandbox.ebay.com/shopping?` **&**  `http://open.api.ebay.com/shopping?`

One is Sandbox and one is Production

> When you join the Developers Program, you are provided with key sets
>   for your application. The keys set for the Sandbox is different from
>   the key set for the Production environment. (Keys for the Sandbox
>   cannot be used to make API calls in the Production environment.
>   Conversely, Production keys cannot be used to make API calls in the
>   Sandbox.)

So your problem **is** the fact that the appID is the same in both URL's. :)
From [Sandbox and Production Keys](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/WebHelp/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm?context=eBay_XML_API&topic=DeveloperKeys)